# How to access object's name property

Tags: javascript

Consider a const that holds an object with multiple levels like this:

```
const test = {
  One: {
    a: 220,
    b: ['Chipotle', 'Subway', 'Habit Burger'],
  },
  Two: {
    a: 110,
    b: ['Chipotle'],
  },
  Three: {
    a: 200,
    b: ['Subway', 'Jack In The Box'],
  },
  Four: {
    a: 460,
    b: ['Chipotle', 'Subway', 'Habit Burger', 'Jack In The Box'],
  },
};
```

I know that, for example, if I want to access the first object's `a` value, I can say `test.One.a`, but how do I programmatically access the value of `test.One`, `test.Two`, etc. without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bracket notation for accessing properties:

```js
test["One"]["a"];
test["Two"]["b"];
```

These work with strings, so you can use variables:

```js
const test = {
  One: {
    a: 220,
    b: ['Chipotle', 'Subway', 'Habit Burger'],
  },
  Two: {
    a: 110,
    b: ['Chipotle'],
  },
  Three: {
    a: 200,
    b: ['Subway', 'Jack In The Box'],
  },
  Four: {
    a: 460,
    b: ['Chipotle', 'Subway', 'Habit Burger', 'Jack In The Box'],
  },
};

const first = Object.keys(test)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
const second = ["a", "b"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];

console.log(first, second, test[first][second])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much

Comment: And if you want to programmatically get the key values of the object, you can use `Object.keys(test)`